# Big O notation of simple expressiosn

Tags: big-o, time-complexity, asymptotic-complexity

Why

```
2n^2 = O(n^3)
```

As definition says

```
if f(n)<= cg(n), 
 n ,c > 0 
for all n > n0
```

and since there can be many upper bounds
So any other and better Upper bound

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question deals with mathematics and not with programming.

Comment: This is a programming question , because in mathematics the "equals =" above is treated as equals but in the above case it is treated as "belongs to".And there is noting in mathematics as big O .

Comment: And if you are looking this way , everything in algorithms(at least in complexity analysis ) is mathematics !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definition from Skiena:

> f(n)=O(g(n)) means c·g(n) is an upper bound on f(n). Thus there exists
>   some constant c such that always `f(n) ≤ c·g(n)`, for large enough n
>   (i.e. , n ≥ n0 for some constant n0).

Here `f(n) = 2n^2, g(n) = n^3`
Let's take constant `c = 2`. So `2n^2 <= 2n^3` for `n >= 1`. So it is true.

Of course you can show the same way that it is `O(n^2)` for same `c = 2`

From wiki:

> A description of a function in terms of big O notation usually only
>   provides an upper bound on the growth rate of the function.

Answer (score 1):

The big O notation only provides an upper bound, so...

> `2n² = O(n²), 2n² = O(n³), ... , 2n² = O(whatever bigger than n²)`

Comment: Thank you !  @marco , it really helped